# Can I send a confirmation E-Mail to imported E-Mail addresses in MailChimp?

Tags: mailchimp, mail

I have a list of E-Mail addresses opting in to subscribe to a newsletter. However, the form that collected the addresses did not send out a "double-opt-in" confirmation E-Mail, which is legally required in the country our web site runs in.

We use MailChimp as our mailing service. MailChimp allows manually adding E-Mail addresses and lists of addresses, but it does not offer sending a confirmation E-Mail to these subscribers - different from those who signed up using MailChimp's own forms.

Is there a way to make MailChimp send a confirmation E-Mail to those addresses after all? Short of entering them all into a form myself?

Comment: A similar thing happened to me and I just created a second mailing list of missing confirmations. Manually.

Comment: You could use Mandrill, if you have access to the code/actually do the programming, which is mailchimp's web api. I've used it myself by just importing the list of emails from my database.

Answer (score 1):

MailChimp's support got back to me and had this to say:

> Unfortunately there would not be a direct way for MailChimp to send
>   out a confirmation email for you, however there is an alternative way
>   to get those people to signup without entering them all one by one
>   into your signup form.
>
> By reconfirming your list, subscribers will be able to click a link to
>   your signup form and sign themselves up and then opt in through our
>   double opt in forms. Please keep in mind this process must be done
>   outside of MailChimp using your normal email client. More information
>   on how to do this can be found here:
>
> How to Reconfirm a List: http://eepurl.com/ec01T

Answer (score 0):

Please turn on the check box for **Send a final welcome email** that you can found from **List Settings**.This will enable you to send a welcome mail to the subscribers when they get added to the corresponding list.

please find more information [here](http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/enable-or-disable-final-welcome-email).

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for - what I need is for a list of new users to be sent the confirmation (opt-in) message. It is legally required in my country.

Comment: aha,my bad, Hope you can find a solution [here](http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/growth/opt-in-methods-for-offline-subscribers).

Comment: @Pekka웃 Did you solved your problem?

Comment: I think no - the link you sent basically says what I already found out above, MailChimp doesn't allow sending opt-in E-Mails to arbitrary addresses. It requires that I manually invite the subscribers to resubscribe through the MailChimp process. There doesn't seem to be a better way unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has not been unsubscribed or deleted, then one can resend the confirmation email, but [editting the user](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#edit-put_lists_list_id_members_subscriber_hash) and setting the `status` to `pending`. Even if it was pending already, then above-written operation will mean that the user gets a new confirmation email.

This is not documented anywhere (only God knows why).